# How do I integrate Github files to Orange for ML?

Tags: orange

[image]

I am currently trying to make a facial recognition workflow with Orange but since the widgets are still prototypes they are not all available in Orange through the add-on menu. I found the Github files for the widgets but don't know how to install this so that I can see and use the widgets in Orange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three ways to install Orange add-ons:

1. The `Options -> Add-ons` menu of Orange.
2. Use pip: `pip3 install orange3-prototypes`
3. Install from the source:

   Terminal commands:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/biolab/orange3-prototypes.git
   cd orange3-prototypes
   python3 setup.py install
   ```

Comment: You see, the github repo in your question has a `setup.py` file right? You can just download this whole repo, decompress, `cd` to the directory you decompressed, and run `python setup.py install`.

Comment: You need to open a Terminal, checkout [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471994/what-is-setup-py) and [this](https://docs.python.org/2/using/mac.html)

Comment: Terminal of your mac system, rather than IDLE.

Comment: In my environment, there's no such error during the installation.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to install it through the *Options > Add-ons* menu in the program.